# Check if GroupBy Key exists

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I have a grouping like so

```
var myGroups = dataItems.GroupBy(item => item.ItemType);
```

How can I check if a key exists in myGroups or not?

Comment: `GroupBy` will only return keys that *do* exist. So what is your question? Do you have a list of keys that you expect to exist?

Comment: Yes, I have a list I expect and then I want to look to see if they have been returned.

Answer (score 6):

I'd use a [`Lookup<TKey, TElement>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var itemTypeLookup = dataItems.ToLookup(item => item.ItemType);
```

Now you can do both, check if a key exists and get the items without querying again:

```
bool typeExists = itemTypeLookup["sampleType"].Any();
```

The advantage over a `GroupBy` is that you can access it as often as you want without executing the query again. The advantage over `ToDictionary`(after `GroupBy`) is that you can access non available keys and you get an empty sequence whereas a dictionary indexer throws an exception. You can't mutate the loookup afterwards and you can use it for LINQ queries because it returns a sequence. Apart from that a lookup and a dictionary are similar and are both very efficient.

Answer (score 4):

Commonly, you would transform that grouping into a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`. You can do so like this:

```
var dictionary = dataItems.GroupBy(item => item.ItemType)
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ToList());
```

If you want to check whether a key exists in that Dictionary, just use:

```
bool keyExists = dictionary.ContainsKey("someKey");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var myGroups = dataItems.GroupBy(item => item.ItemType);

var exists = myGroups.Any(x => x.Key == "testName");
```

You can use the `Any` method of linq, it saves time as it will stop searching as soon as it finds a match.

Comment: While this is correct, if the OP wanted to check 2 keys, the entire query would have to run again. Also, please read [answer] since code-only answers are discouraged on this site.

Comment: Multiple keys are simple enough with a compound lambda condition surely?

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case you don't need transform grouping to Dictionary and search will stop on first occurrence of the item with key which is needed.

```
bool exist = myGroups.First(x => x.Key == "keyName") != null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean that you would like to check a bunch of keys

> Yes, I have a list I expect and then I want to look to see if they have been returned.

Here's one way to check if ALL expected group keys are present, arguably not very efficient:

```
var dataToBeGrouped = new []{4,4,1,2,1,2,1};

var grp = dataToBeGrouped.GroupBy(z => z);
var allKeysPresent = grp.Select(g => g.Key)
   .OrderBy(k => k)
   .SequenceEqual(new[]{1,2,4});
```

Where `new[]{1,2,4}` is the set of ordered, expected keys.

As an alternative to ordered checking, you could create a set of actual keys, and then ensure all are present:

```
var keysToCheck = new HashSet<int>(grp.Select(g => g.Key));
var allKeysPresent = new[]{1,2,4}.All(k => keysToCheck.Contains(k));
```